# Tiger Configuration Ignore a file format

Tags: command-line, server, configuration

So on my Ubuntu 16.04 Server I'm encountering the following error from Tiger.

```
--CONFIG-- [con010c] Filesystem 'tracefs' used by 'tracefs' is not recognised as a valid filesystem
```

A fix for this I found was to go into `/etc/tiger/tigerrc` and on the `Tiger_FSScan_Local=` line add the file system in the quotes.

When I opened the `tigerrc` file I found the line with a file name already in place.

```
Tiger_FSScan_Local='.lxcfs'
```

My question is how do I add another filesystem to this line?

To be clear I am trying to add tracefs to the Tiger_FSScan_Local line and it already has one filesystem on the line.

I'm not even sure how to tag this...

**Edit**
So I tried to add `.tracefs` as `Tiger_FSScan_Local='.lxcfs .tracefs'`.
That didn't fix the issue, kind of made it worse. Going to add on the following line indicating non-Local.

**Edit**
This is how I tried having it set as well, still receiving the same error. Does anybody know which pip separator Tiger needs/prefers?

```
Tiger_FSScan_Local='.lxcfs'             # Filesystems considered to be local to the system, pipe-separated
Tiger_FSScan_NonLocal='.tracefs'        # Filesystems considered to be non-local to the system, pipe-separated
```

**Edit** This made it worse!

```
Tiger_FSScan_Local='.lxcfs''.tracefs'           # Filesystems considered to be $
Tiger_FSScan_NonLocal=  # Filesystems considered to be non-local to the system,$
```

Returned the following:

```
--CONFIG-- [con010c] Filesystem 'tracefs' used by 'tracefs' is not recognised as a valid filesystem
--CONFIG-- [con010c] Filesystem 'fuse.lxcfs' used by 'lxcfs' is not recognised as a valid filesystem
```

**Edit** Changed the format to the following and it didn't work either.

```
Tiger_FSScan_Local='.lxcfs';'.tracefs'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tiger, but the example [here](https://github.com/phith0n/tiger/blob/master/tigerrc) suggests it should accept a pipe-separated list

Comment: So it would be `Tiger_FSScan_Local='.lxcfs' | '.tracefs'?`

Comment: IDK - regardless, I would think you'd want to add to `Tiger_FSScan_NonLocal` if you want it to be ignored, no? From [Tiger-announce](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/tiger-announce/2008-09/msg00000.html) *"filesystems defined in it will be considered non-local and will not be analysed. This allows administrators to add there esoteric filessystems in use so that they can work around the 'unknown filesystem' report generated by gen_mounts until it gets updated upstream."*

Comment: By this following link I'm supposed to add it to the Local line, not sure why but it didn't fix it and/or I didn't add it correctly. I will try it how you recommended and see what happens. https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2100345.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to fix this issue I found the following debian bug id [#791352](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=791352)

In message N°5 from Mr. Theodore Kotz I found his solution that worked for me:

> "An entry needs to be added to
>   /usr/lib/tiger/systems/Linux/2/gen_mounts.  In mine, I just cloned the
>   debugfs line, and put tracefs in place of debugfs"

Relevant lines from my /usr/lib/tiger/systems/Linux/2/gen_mounts, clone this:

```
[ "$1" = "debugfs" ] && LOCAL=1
```

Paste one line down and change debugfs to tracefs:

```
[ "$1" = "tracefs" ] && LOCAL=1
```

So the file results in:

```
...
[ "$1" = "debugfs" ] && LOCAL=1
[ "$1" = "tracefs" ] && LOCAL=1
...
```